# How to change the getrowid to id

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysqli, jqxgrid

can anyone tell me how to change the getrowid to get the value of the selected id, i need to get the value of the selected id to pass to the sql.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.classic.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // prepare the data
            var data = {};
            var theme = 'classic';
            var ide= new Array();
           var namee= new Array();
            var emaile= new Array();
            var subjecte= new Array();
            var confirmcodee= new Array();
            var usernamee= new Array();
            var passworde= new Array();


            var generaterow = function () {
                var row = {};
                var firtnameindex = ide.length-1;
                row["id"] = ide[firtnameindex];
                row["name"] = namee[firtnameindex];
                row["email"] = emaile[firtnameindex];
                row["subject"] = subjecte[firtnameindex];
                row["confirmcode"] = confirmcodee[firtnameindex];
                row["username"] = usernamee[firtnameindex];
                row["password"] = passworde[firtnameindex];
                return row;

            }






            var source =
            {   

                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                     { name: 'id' },
                     { name: 'name' },
                     { name: 'email' },
                     { name: 'subject' },
                     { name: 'confirmcode' },
                     { name: 'username' },
                     { name: 'password' }
                ],


                ide: 'id',
                url: 'data.php',
                addrow: function (rowid, rowdata) {
                    // synchronize with the server - send insert command
                    var data = "insert=true&" + $.param(rowdata);
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'data.php',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            // insert command is executed.
                        }
                    });
                },
                deleterow: function (rowdata) {
                    // synchronize with the server - send delete command
                    var data = "delete=true&id=" + rowdata;
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'data.php',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            // delete command is executed.
                        }
                    });
                },
                updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata) {
                    // synchronize with the server - send update command
                    var data = "update=true&" + $.param(rowdata);
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'data.php',
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            // update command is executed.
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            // initialize jqxGrid
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 500,
                height: 350,
                source: source,
                theme: theme,
                columns: [
                      { text: 'id', datafield: 'id', width: 100 },
                      { text: 'name', datafield: 'name', width: 100 },
                      { text: 'email', datafield: 'email', width: 100 },
                      { text: 'subject', datafield: 'subject', width: 180 },
                      { text: 'confirmcode', datafield: 'confirmcode', width: 180 },
                      { text: 'username', datafield: 'username', width: 100 },
                      { text: 'password', datafield: 'password', width: 140 }
                  ]
            });
            $("#addrowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });
            $("#deleterowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });
            $("#updaterowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });
            // update row.
            $("#updaterowbutton").bind('click', function () {
                var datarow = generaterow();
                var selectedrowindex = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
                var rowscount = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getdatainformation').rowscount;
                if (selectedrowindex >= 0 && selectedrowindex < rowscount) {
                    var ide = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowid', selectedrowindex);
                    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updaterow', ide, datarow);
                }
            });
            // create new row.
            $("#addrowbutton").bind('click', function () {
            var idw = prompt("Enter ID","");
                ide.push(idw);
                var namew = prompt("Enter name","");
                namee.push(namew);
                var emailw = prompt("Enter email","");
                emaile.push(emailw);
                var subjectw = prompt("Enter subject","");
                subjecte.push(subjectw);
                var confirmcodew = prompt("Enter confirm code","");
                confirmcodee.push(confirmcodew);
                var usernamew = prompt("Enter username","");
                usernamee.push(usernamew);
                var passwordw = prompt("Enter password for the username","");
                passworde.push(passwordw);
                var rowscount = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getdatainformation').rowscount;
                var datarow = generaterow();
                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, datarow);
            });
            // delete row.
            $("#deleterowbutton").bind('click', function () {
                var selectedrowindex = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
                var rowscount = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getdatainformation').rowscount;
                if (selectedrowindex >= 0 && selectedrowindex < rowscount) {
                    var ide = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowid', selectedrowindex);
                    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('deleterow', ide);
                }
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div style="float: left;" id="jqxgrid">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 30px; float: left;">

             <div>
                <input id="addrowbutton" type="button" value="Add New Row" />
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <input id="deleterowbutton" type="button" value="Delete Selected Row" />
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <input id="updaterowbutton" type="button" value="Update Selected Row" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

I need to change the getrowid into get the value of id in the selected row, how???

This is my data.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
#Include the connect.php file
include('connect.php');
#Connect to the database
//connection String
$connect = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
//Select The database
$bool = mysql_select_db($database, $connect);
if ($bool === False){
   print "can't find $database";
}
// get data and store in a json array
$query = "SELECT * FROM weekang";
if (isset($_GET['insert']))
{
    // INSERT COMMAND 
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `weekang`(`id`, `name`, `email`, `subject`, `confirmcode`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('".$_GET['id']."','".$_GET['name']."','".$_GET['email']."','".$_GET['subject']."','".$_GET['confirmcode']."','".$_GET['username']."','".$_GET['password']."')";

   $result = mysql_query($insert_query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
   echo $result;
}
else if (isset($_GET['update']))
{
    // UPDATE COMMAND 
    $update_query = "UPDATE `weekang` SET `name`='".$_GET['name']."',
    `email`='".$_GET['email']."',
    `subject`='".$_GET['subject']."',
    `confirmcode`='".$_GET['confirmcode']."',
    `username`='".$_GET['username']."',
    `password`='".$_GET['password']."' WHERE `id`='".$_GET['id']."'";
     $result = mysql_query($update_query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
     echo $result;
}
else if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    // DELETE COMMAND 
    $delete_query = "DELETE FROM `weekang` WHERE `id`='".$_GET['id']."'";   
    $result = mysql_query($delete_query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
    echo $result;
}
else
{
    // SELECT COMMAND
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $weekang[] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
            'subject' => $row['subject'],
            'confirmcode' => $row['confirmcode'],
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'password' => $row['password']
          );
    }

    echo json_encode($weekang);
}
?>
```

Comment: what `username`?  You need to give us more to go on here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'getrowdata' method instead. It will return the data record at specific index.

Comment: My coding I had uploaded. can you please help me how can i get the selected id data for SQL DELETE FROM `weekang` WHERE `id`='".$_GET['id']."' to delete the selected row using the those id. thanks